# Flash Player Projector post 2020

Tags: flash, adobe, flex3, flashplayer-debug

We have an internal Flash application current running in browsers.

Can we use [Flash Player Projector](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/32/flashplayer_32_sa.exe) app post 2020 and configure our SWF URL to run in this application.

Will the Flash Player Support End from Adobe impact the way we can use the Flash Player Projector app (flashplayer_32_sa.exe)

I have researched other blogs and SO questions which mostly talks about the Flash Player Browser Plugin Support and none for the Project App.

Comment: You can actually wind the system clock 1 year ahead and check it then tell us all.

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: What if Microsoft pushes a new patch during the start of 2021 to prevent flash playing.

Comment: Standalone projector is just another program, why do you think Microsoft would care about it specifically? With the same level of probability you can assume Microsoft would try to kill Notepad++, Chrome or VLC media player. 2020 is the end of Flash Plugin for browsers as it is now, AIR applications and standalone installments are doubtfully to be affected. Also, you might want to read this: https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still wondering, my Flash Player Projector functionality (flashplayer_32_sa.exe) was not affected by Adobe's disabling of the browser plugin, or from uninstalling that version. I did take the precaution of placing the Flash Player Projector in a separate location from the regular Flash files.

Comment: Is there a tutorial that you can still use your own SWF file with this projector? That would be very interesting for an internal tool that had to die because too little important to rewrite it, but useful enough to bring it back to life that way.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to use the projector: 

https://openswffile.com/standalone-windows-no-browser.html

Comment: Be aware that you can no longer download flashplayer_32_sa.exe from Adobe's website; you would have to find it hosted somewhere else.

Comment: Debug version of flashplayer_32_sa is still available from Adobe, and worked for me: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Comment: That debug version link doesn't work at all anymore. Adobe replaced it with a "We have retired Flash" page. 

Comment: @PaulMignard You can still use the [web archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20210714135833/https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html)  or one of the third party cached variants.